# When using inline formsets with form wizards, where does formset form validation go?

Tags: inline-formset, django-formwizard

I am creating an example to learn more about using inline formsets with SessionWizard. Eventually, I want to integrate dynamic formsets in order to add and delete individual forms via the template before submitting. However, when data is absent from the second form, it fails to validate unlike like a regular ModelForm.

Is there a method within SessionWizard that needs to be overridden? Is it something that is inherently handled within Django?

Guidance and examples would be greatly appreciated.

models.py

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return name

class Child(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return name
```

urls.py

```
test_forms = [['parent', ParentForm],['child', ChildFormSet]]

urlpatterns = patterns('example.views',
    url(r'^$', TestWizard.as_view(test_forms)),
)
```

forms.py

```
class ParentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Parent

class ChildForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Child
        exclude = ('parent',)

ChildFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Parent, Child, extra=1)

class TestWizard(SessionWizardView):
    """
    This WizardView is used to create multi-page forms and handles all the
    storage and validation stuff using sessions.
    """
    #template_name = ''

#    def get_template_names(self):
#        """
#        Returns a list of template names to be used for the request.
#        Overridden TemplateResponseMixin for specifying template for step.
#        """
#        return 'survey/forms/wizard_form.html'
#
#    def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
#        context = super(TestWizard, self).get_context_data(form=form, **kwargs)
#        return context
#
#    def get_form_initial(self, step):
#        """
#        Returns dict (list of key, values) for initial form data.
#        Useful for populating form fields with data from prior form, with extra
#        logic for dealing with formsets.
#        """
#        return self.initial_dict.get(step, {})
#
#    def get_form(self, step=None, data=None, files=None):
#        """
#        Constructs the form for a given step - overridden to add extra arguments
#        """
#        form = super(TestWizard, self).get_form(step, data, files)
#        return form

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        return render_to_response('survey/thanks.html', {
            'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],
        })
```

wizard-form.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block head %}
    {{ wizard.form.media }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <p>DEFAULT WIZARD FORM Step {{ wizard.steps.step1 }} of {{ wizard.steps.count }}</p>
    <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        <table>
            {{ wizard.management_form }}
            {% if wizard.form.forms %}
                {{ wizard.form.management_form }}
                {% for form in wizard.form.forms %}
                    {{ form }}
                {% endfor %}
            {% else %}
                {{ wizard.form }}
            {% endif %}
        </table>
        {% if wizard.steps.prev %}
            <button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.first }}">{% trans "first step" %}</button>
            <button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}">{% trans "prev step" %}</button>
        {% endif %}
        <input type="submit" value="{% trans "submit" %}"/>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```